# Magento 2 How to add custom sort by option

Tags: magento2, sorting

I need to add an additional filter based on `created_at` attribute for sorting product list by latest product. I tried to figure it using below file

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml
```

but how can add our entity id to `getAvailableOrders()` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to use an attribute like `created_at` that it isn't in admin->stores->(attribute) product, because attributes defined in admin have the setting `Sorting in Product Listing = Yes/No`, you have to work with these two files:

> `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php`
>   `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Config.php`

In `Toolbar.php` you can see

```
$this->_availableOrder = $this->_catalogConfig->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
```

it calls `getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()` from `Config.php` that returns array of available attributes to sort listing collection.

Now, you have to add your `created_at` attribute here.
How?
I did it with a **plugin**

```
/**
 * Add sort order option created_at to frontend
 */
public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    $options
) {
    $options['created_at'] = __('New');
    return $options;
}
```

You inserted `created_at` in available attributes to sort, now you have only to build your custom collection to use it.
Here i choose **to override** `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php` with mine `Toolbar.php` and override `setCollection()`

```
/**
 * Set collection to pager
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
 * @return $this
 */
 public function setCollection($collection) {
    $this->_collection = $collection;
    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }

    // switch between sort order options
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        // create custom query for created_at option
        switch ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            case 'created_at':
                if ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc') {
                    $this->_collection
                        ->getSelect()
                        ->order('e.created_at DESC');
                } elseif ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc') {
                    $this->_collection
                        ->getSelect()
                        ->order('e.created_at ASC');           
                }
                break;
            default:
                $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
                break;
        }
    }

    // echo '<pre>';
    // var_dump($this->getCurrentOrder());
    // var_dump((string) $this->_collection->getSelect());
    // die;

    return $this;        
}
```

That's all, for me works like a charm.

Comment: If anyone wants to default to ascending, then change `} elseif ( $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc' ) {` to `} else {`.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to use a plugin, you can also use the built-in public function `$block->addOrderToAvailableOrders('created_at', 'New')` in your sorter template.

Comment: Can you have the solution for sorting custom product price? **@Luca**

Comment: @DhadukMitesh sure, you could just use the above code and change attribute code `created_at` with your custom price attribute code

Comment: I have no custom price attribute. I use default price sort by. I only change in core file where price is sorting. and I want to set my custom price for a collection. but I can't set custom price in collection.

Comment: Your request is not related to this post.

Comment: You don't need to override the Toolbar.php at all in this implementation since `$this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection())` does exactly that by default in the original class, so you only need to add a sorting option with the matching attribute code

Comment: check this [improved sorting](https://www.mageants.com/improved-sorting-for-magento-2.html) extension for sort by option it will work

Comment: Its not working for me with same files can you please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354786/custom-sorting-option-not-working-in-magetno-2-4-search

Answer (score 23):

We can achieve it by using Plugins.
Please create following files in your module.

**app/code/Package/CustomToolbar/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
    <plugin name="Package_CustomToolbar::addCustomOptions" type="Package\CustomToolbar\Plugin\Model\Config" />
</type>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
    <plugin name="Package_CustomToolbar::addPriceDecendingFilterInToolbar" type="Package\CustomToolbar\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
</type>
```

**app/code/Package/CustomToolbar/Plugin/Model/Config.php**

```
namespace Package\CustomToolbar\Plugin\Model;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
class Config
{
    protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;

}

/**
 * Adding custom options and changing labels
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
 * @param [] $options
 * @return []
 */
public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
{
    $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    $currencySymbol = $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();

    //Remove specific default sorting options
    unset($options['position']);
    unset($options['name']);
    unset($options['price']);

    //Changing label
    $customOption['position'] = __('Relevance');

    //New sorting options
    $customOption['price_desc'] = __($currencySymbol.' (High to Low)');
    $customOption['price_asc'] = __($currencySymbol.' (Low to High)');

    //Merge default sorting options with custom options
    $options = array_merge($customOption, $options);

    return $options;
}
}
```

**app/code/Package/CustomToolbar/Plugin/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php**

```
namespace Package\CustomToolbar\Plugin\Product\ProductList;
class Toolbar
{
    /**
     * Plugin
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
     */
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $result = $proceed($collection);

        if ($currentOrder) {
            if ($currentOrder == 'price_desc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
            } elseif ($currentOrder == 'price_asc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

This is working fine for me without rewriting any Magento class.

Comment: this doesn't address created_at and not working for 2.1.9 - for me at least

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how aroundSetCollection works?

Comment: hi @Sumit, can you update the same for Best seller sort

Comment: Hi @sumit, It's not working in Magento 2,4,1 version for me. Can you help?

Comment: Its not working for me with same files can you please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354786/custom-sorting-option-not-working-in-magetno-2-4-search

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use just *Create At* attribute, you can activate this attribute in admin panel in sorting options.

Example:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * UpgradeData constructor.
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.1.1', '<')) {
            try {
                $entityType = $eavSetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
                $label = 'Created At';
                $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'created_at', 'frontend_label', $label, null);
                $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'created_at', 'used_for_sort_by', 1, null);
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code from *Setup/UpgradeData.php*, but will be better to use *InstallData.php* instead.

Comment: Where is this code added in the file system?

Comment: Why create a custom module to change a db field? i don't think is the best way.

Comment: Its not working for me with same files can you please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354786/custom-sorting-option-not-working-in-magetno-2-4-search

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1**: First you should create registration.php

Vendor name: Arun

Module name: NewSorting

> Vendor/Modulename/registration.php

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Arun_NewSorting',
__DIR__
);?>
```

**Step 2**: You create module.xml

> Vendor/Modulename/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Arun_NewSorting" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3**: You create plugin

> Vendor/Modulename/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="Arun_NewSorting::addCustomOptions" type="Arun\NewSorting\Plugin\Model\Config" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="Arun_NewSorting::addPriceDecendingFilterInToolbar" type="Arun\NewSorting\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step 4**: then create config.php

> Vendor/Modulename/Plugin/Model/Config.php

```
<?php
namespace Arun\NewSorting\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Config  {


    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }


    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $currencySymbol = $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();

        // Remove specific default sorting options
        $default_options = [];
        $default_options['name'] = $options['name'];

        unset($options['position']);
        unset($options['name']);
        unset($options['price']);

        //Changing label
        $customOption['position'] = __( 'Relevance' );

        //New sorting options
        $customOption['created_at'] = __( ' New' );


        $customOption['name'] = $default_options['name'];

        //Merge default sorting options with custom options
        $options = array_merge($customOption, $options);

        return $options;
    }
}
```

**Step 5**: Override the Toolbar.php***

> Vendor/Modulename/Plugin/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Arun\NewSorting\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{

    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $result = $proceed($collection);

        if ($currentOrder) {
            if ($currentOrder == 'created_at') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
            } 
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

it's work perfectly

Comment: Any commands to be run in CLI after updating these files please?

Comment: Need to run following CLI setup upgrade, static-content deploy, cache clean, reindex

Comment: Thanks MSA but when I run the upgrade command it says 'nothing to update'. Using 2.2.5. Copied all of the above... but wondered what is in Registration.php file you mention and where to locate it?

Comment: I updated Registration.php file content                                                                                                                 path:Vendor/Modulename/registration.php

Comment: Added module exactly as above and the 'new' option shows on front end. It seems to have replaced the 'position' option is that expected? I cannot see the option in catalog in admin panel, as I would like to make this default option... Thank you.

Comment: The sort by price is removed when I use this module on my instance.. is there anyway just to add the 'new' without losing price?

Comment: @ArunprabakaranM, I m trying to get Best seller sort by, but this solution not working '

Comment: Im on version 2.3.1, this worked like a charm for me using `created_at`, life saver thanks!

Comment: Its not working for me with same files can you please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354786/custom-sorting-option-not-working-in-magetno-2-4-search

Answer (score 2):

## The way doesn't need write codes

1. Find the `created_at` product attribute in DB table `eav_attribute`, set its column `frontend_label` to `Created At`(default is null).
2. Find the `created_at` product attribute in DB table `catalog_eav_attribute`, set its column `used_for_sort_by` to `1`(default is 0).
3. Clean site cache and it is working.

### Example: change table by mysql

```sql
# Get the attribute_id of 'created_at'
select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'created_at' and entity_type_id=4;

# Set frontend_label
update eav_attribute set frontend_label = 'Created At' where attribute_id=112;

# Set used_for_sort_by
update catalog_eav_attribute set used_for_sort_by = 1 where attribute_id=112;
```

Comment: I wouldn't directly change the db values, especially if it's core data.

Comment: @LucScu It is just a another easier way. It changed two DB field that don't matter. You could use codes to override function too, but the covered function will be changed in version upgrade, and you have to update your custom codes. Both methods have advantages and disadvantages. Use custom codes for a simple function is a bit of overkill.

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR I used it and it is working. Pay attention to using the right `attribute_id`.

Comment: @KeyShang my bad, its working perfectly, upvoted :)

Comment: This didn't work for me.
I can see sorting option "created at" but when I sort by I get no products shown.
"We can't find products matching the selection."
Using Elasticsearch Magento 2.4.1. I think the issue is caused by using ElasticSearch default search engine ( there is no other options as of Magento 2.4x)

Comment: @ChrisOliver Yes, ElasticSearch should have some other settings. I haven't used Magento 2.4.x yet.

Comment: Its not working for me with same files can you please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354786/custom-sorting-option-not-working-in-magetno-2-4-search

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that if you are using Magento 2.4.x with Elastic Search - that the direct database change previously recommended (by Key Shang) will cause pages that include the toolbar to break and or work inconsistently. To fix, disable the used_to_sort_by option for the created_at attribute, and find another way to achieve this.

Comment: This is working fine for me in Magento 2.4.x - no problems using created_at as sort option with ES.

Comment: Its not working for me with same files can you please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354786/custom-sorting-option-not-working-in-magetno-2-4-search

Answer (score 0):

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php \vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Config.php
```

https://prnt.sc/w6nehd

```
$this->_availableOrder = $this->_catalogConfig->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
```

`

```
class Toolbar
{
    public function aroundSetCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
                                        \Closure $proceed, $collection)
    {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $result = $proceed($collection);
        if($currentOrder)
        {
            if($currentOrder == 'high_to_low')
            {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
            }
            elseif ($currentOrder == 'low_to_high')
            {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->reset('order');
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
`

`class Config
{
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
        $options['low_to_high'] = __('Price - Low To High');
        $options['high_to_low'] = __('Price - High To Low');
        return $options;
    }
}`
```

Comment: Its not working for me with same files can you please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354786/custom-sorting-option-not-working-in-magetno-2-4-search