# Magento 2 Sort By Price: Low to High and High to Low

Tags: magento2

I want to custom sort by option in category Filter For price like this **Price: Low to High & Price: High to Low.**
Please suggest me how to change sorting option in my site.
i am using magento 2.1.2

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-sort-by-option

Comment: Use my module https://github.com/springimport/magento2-module-catalog-dropdown-sort

Comment: Your module look exactly what I need. Could you give me instructions on how to install it?

Comment: @MykhailoShatilov your module showing invalid template error for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create plugins

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="custom_custom_block_toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Toolbar" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="custom_catalog_model_config" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Config" />
    </type>

</config>
```

**Step 2:** Create **Config.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Config.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

class Config
{
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    $options
    ) {

        $options['low_to_high'] = __('Price - Low To High');
        $options['high_to_low'] = __('Price - High To Low');
        return $options;

    }

}
```

**Step 3:** Create **Toolbar.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Block/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block;

class Toolbar
{

    /**
    * Plugin
    *
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
    * @param \Closure $proceed
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
    */
    public function aroundSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $collection
    ) {
    $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
    $result = $proceed($collection);

    if ($currentOrder) {
        if ($currentOrder == 'high_to_low') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
        } elseif ($currentOrder == 'low_to_high') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
        }
    }

    return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Its not working. I tried to apply it in Magento 2.1.6

Comment: No. Its not working in firefox as well. Your mention jquery function is not called.

Comment: See my updated code

Comment: Not working man

Comment: it's working on my side. what problem are you facing ?

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: can we add another drop down called most popular?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many as you want.

Comment: It doesn't work for me for products with special_price. Can you check if it is working with a mixed set of products, without special price and with special price?

Comment: It's not working for Product with special Price, Any solution??

Comment: Thanks bro :) working fine with 2.3.0 and tested

Comment: Thanks bro. I combined the code from this link with your code above, and it worked on version 2.3.4
https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-magento-2-sort-by-price-for-low-to-high-high-to-low-options/

Comment: This code is not working in the latest M2.4.* versions. is anybody have the solution for the same ?