# Magento 2 - Custom sort order not working properly

Tags: magento2, category-products, sorting, sort, product-sorting

I have created a custom plugin for sorting options for high to low & low to high price. High to low sort works fine but "low to high" sort order not showing correct results.

**app/code/Digital/CustomSort/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
    <plugin name="digital_customsort_block_product_productlist_toolbar" type="Digital\CustomSort\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="digital_customsort_model_config" type="Digital\CustomSort\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Config" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Digital/CustomSort/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Config.php**

```
<?php
//namespace Digital\CustomSort\Plugin\Model;
//class Config extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config

namespace Digital\CustomSort\Plugin\Catalog\Model;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config as CatalogConfig;

class Config
{
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(CatalogConfig $subject, $result)
    {
        $result['low_to_high'] = __('Price - Low To High');
        $result['high_to_low'] = __('Price - High To Low');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Digital/CustomSort/Plugin/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php**

```
<?php
 //namespace Digital\CustomSort\Plugin\Block\Product\ProductList;
 //class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar

namespace Digital\CustomSort\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar as ProductListToolbar;

class Toolbar
{
    public function afterSetCollection(ProductListToolbar $subject, $result, $collection)
    {
        switch ($subject->getCurrentOrder()) {
            case 'low_to_high':
                return $result->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
            case 'high_to_low':
                return $result->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
            default:
                return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is really similar to this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/163433/70343

Have you seen this answer? Makes sense to me although some users have said it doesnt work.

Plus it doesnt factor special pricing.

Comment: I tried this solution but not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

> Digital/CustomSort/Plugin/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Digital\CustomSort\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar as ProductListToolbar;

class Toolbar
{
    public function afterSetCollection(ProductListToolbar $subject, $result, $collection)
    {
        switch ($subject->getCurrentOrder()) {
            case 'low_to_high':
                $result->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
                break;
            case 'high_to_low':
                $result->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
                break;
            default:
                // Add a default sorting here if needed
                break;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I removed unnecessary calls to $result->getCollection(). The collection is already available as a parameter, so you can directly use it.

I added break; statements after each case to exit the switch statement once a case is matched. This prevents fall-through to the default case, ensuring that only one sorting option is applied.

After making these changes, clear the cache and test the "low to high" and "high to low" sorting options in your Magento store.