# How to show highest prices products on top in Magento2 categrory pages?

Tags: magento2

I want to show the highest priced products when enter any category page.
Is there any configuration in Admin pnael I should do ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Stores - Settings - Configuration - Catalog - Storefront` and change `Product Listing Sort by` to `Price`

Also you can try [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/163433/32730)