# Help with Magento 2.3 custom product sort plugin

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento2.3, product-sorting

I have tried to implement a custom sorting plugin in Magento. Namely, with the options:

Price (Low > High)

Price (High > Low)

Name (A - Z)

Name (Z - A)

Now, I have the plugin installed and working, with code very similar to the examples in similar posts such as [Magento 2 How to add custom sort by option](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-sort-by-option).

Sorting by price works brilliantly, however, I'm struggling to get the correct join, in order to get the sorting by Name working. Take the code below in my plugins `Toolbar.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
    /**
    * Plugin
    *
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
    * @param \Closure $proceed
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
    */
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $currentOrder = $toolbar->getCurrentOrder();
        $currentDirection = $toolbar->getCurrentDirection();
        $result = $proceed($collection);

        if ($currentOrder) {
            switch ($currentOrder) {

            case 'price_desc':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('price_index.min_price DESC');
            break;

            case 'price_asc':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('price_index.min_price ASC');
            break;

            case 'name_az':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('e.name ASC');
            break;

            case 'name_za':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('e.name DESC');
            break;

            default:        
                $this->_collection
                    ->setOrder($currentOrder, $currentDirection);
            break;

            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

As mentioned, sorting by price works fine, but when trying to sort by name, I get an error something along the lines of,

> there is no column name on e

I understand that I need to perform a more complex join query to get the product name from the `product_entity_varchar` table but can't for the life of me seem to get it working or fully understand the syntax.

Some help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `setOrder` method for sorting and pass the attribute name for a loaded attribute (e.g. `name`). This should work for you:

```
case 'name_az':
    $this->_collection
       ->setOrder('name', 'ASC');
break;

case 'name_za':
    $this->_collection
        ->setOrder('name', 'DESC');
break;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you @HelgeB 

Comment: Great to hear that it works for you. It would be good if you would accept the answer, that may help others with a similar problem to find the solution.