# Sorting by product ID

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, sorting

I'd like to add **product id** as a new sorting option in frontend catalog pages. How can I do that?

This attribute is not listed in product attributes configuration in magento backend. I guess that it can be done by custom extension but I don't know how. Could you post a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is follow this link [Magento 2 How to add custom sort by option](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-sort-by-option/195138#195138) , override this two files as @LucScu mentioned:

> \vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php
>
> \vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Config.php

and modify the code for your case ,
instead of **created_at** add **entity_id**.

Note ! Do not `copy -> paste` his code, but change the files based on your magento2 version (he may had a lower magento2 version) .

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, by making another custom product attribute `latest_products` and it's label of your choice which you want to show on category page `sort by`. Don't assign it on any `Attribute Set` so it will not show against each product edit admin page.

Make sure you set the `Used in Product listing` to `Yes` in your newly made custom attribute

[image]

After you created the attribute, Go to categories in admin select your desired category  and Go to `Display setting` and check newly created attribute is selected in `Available Product listing Sort By`.

[image]

In code, Add `di.xml` in `Vendor/Module/etc/frontend` in your custom module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
</config>
```

After Add `Toolbar.php` file in your module `Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        if($this->getCurrentOrder()=="latest_products")
        {
              $collection->getSelect()->order("e.entity_id desc");
        }

        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**I hope this will help and cover what you are required**

Comment: This could be a solution, but it requires creating a new attribute. I'd like to use en existing attribute, which is product id