# Magento 2 sorting configurable products by special_price is not working

Tags: configurable-product, product-list, magento2.3.0, special-price, product-sorting

I have simple and configurable products on listing page.

I am using `special_price` attribute for sorting. It is working for simple products but not working for configurable products.

I have assigned special_price for all associated products of configurable products but still it is not sorting.

I am using Magento 2.3.0. Can anyone suggest how can I do?

Comment: instead of `special_price` try to sort your collection by `minimal_price`

Comment: @ShoaibMunir, I am talking about default collection on category page.minimal_price is not available by default.

Comment: create new custom attribute 'Price Low to High' or something like this, and create you own sorting by `minimal_price` follow this for custom sorting https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275793/sorting-by-product-id/275796#275796

Comment: @ShoaibMunir, can we not do using existing attribute special price?

Comment: I guess it would be nearly impossible without custom coding