# How to change products sort order in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, product-list, sorting, product-sorting

In product list page I need to change the sorting order. I have a current order like:

- Description A-Z
- Price High To Low
- Price Low  to High
- Description Z-A

I need to change it to.

- Description A-Z
- Description Z-A
- Price High To Low
- Price Low  to High

I tried using this JS.

```
window.onload = () => {
        const fontMenu = document.querySelector("#sorter");
        const options = Array.from(fontMenu.querySelectorAll("option"));
        // options.reverse();
             options.forEach((item,o) => {
                 options.splice(0,3);
                console.log(options,'op')
                options.unshift(item);
                fontMenu.appendChild(item);

             });
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think there are two ways.

1. Create your own sort option in a module using a plugin. Something like this: [Magento 2 How to add custom sort by option](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-sort-by-option). Look at Luca S's answer. I think this person has a general idea of how to do it.
2. Use Position option but modified: http://magento2x.com/magento-sort-newest-products-solution/.

Hopefully this will Help You.