# how to align the custom order option in magento 2 in product list page sort by options

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml, admin-panel

how to align the custom order option in magento 2 in product list page sort by options ?

[image]

how to set the custom order in attributes using Short by options ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there are two ways.

1. Create your own sort option in a module using a plugin. Something like this: Magento 2 How to add [custom sort by option](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-sort-by-option). Look at Luca S's answer. I think this person has a general idea of how to do it.
2. Use Position option but modified: http://magento2x.com/magento-sort-newest-products-solution/.

Hopefully this will Help You.

Comment: Its not working in short by options

Comment: did you try Luca S's answer.

Comment: yes i try  this, but its not working

Comment: Please try another option