# Magento 2.4.1 sort by newest not working

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, product-sorting, magento2.4.1

I am using Magento 2.4.1 search engine is elasticsearch7 selected in catalog config. I wanted to add custom sorting options on the category page like sort by price low to high and newest etc. Now I am using the below code which is working for the price but not with the newest.

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{

    /**
     * Set collection to pager
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
     */
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {

        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        
        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            if (($this->getCurrentOrder()) == 'position') {
                $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort(
                    $this->getCurrentOrder(),
                    $this->getCurrentDirection()
                );
            } elseif ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'price_desc') {
                $this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'desc');
            } elseif ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'price_asc') {
                $this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'asc');
            } elseif ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'newest') {
                $this->_collection->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
                //NOT WORKING
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Giving me this error in exception.log

> main.CRITICAL:
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text
> fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document
> field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are
> disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead.
> Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [created_at] in order to load
> field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use
> significant
> memory."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
> shards
> failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v84","node":"YYnx_-CIRyOYDAqvIIU_BQ","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text
> fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document
> field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are
> disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead.
> Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [created_at] in order to load
> field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use
> significant
> memory."}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text
> fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document
> field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are
> disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead.
> Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [created_at] in order to load
> field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use
> significant
> memory.","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text
> fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document
> field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are
> disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead.
> Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [created_at] in order to load
> field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use
> significant memory."}}},"status":400} {"exception":"[object]
> (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400):

Any help would be great.

Comment: Check this answer for a simple way to enable created_at sorting in frontend https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/287793/7863

Comment: Yes, that works but Should I change the value of the database table OR there is a better way. That's why I am waiting if someone knows any other way

Comment: This sounds like it is related to the officially confirmed bug [#31043](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31043).

Comment: Yes because maybe when I used `addAttributeToSort` I was not getting any error but the product list was staying as it is when I try to sort by newest. If you find a correct solution please post your answer here so It can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this is the correct way to do this or not. I was waiting for someone to give a better answer but not getting one. So I am using this for now.

```
# Get the attribute_id of 'created_at'
select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'created_at' and entity_type_id=4;

# Set frontend_label
update eav_attribute set frontend_label = 'Created At' where attribute_id=112;

# Set used_for_sort_by
update catalog_eav_attribute set used_for_sort_by = 1 where attribute_id=112;
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working in the current 2.4 version.. Is this all you did on the MySQL end? No other file changes?

Answer (score 1):

https://marketplace.magento.com/sparsh-magento-2-advanced-sorting-extension.html

This works with 2.4.1 - Makes the sort by functionality actually work as expected.