# custom sorting is not working in magento 2.4.3 p1

Tags: custom-attributes, product-sorting, magento2.4.3.p1

`enter code here`I am created a custom sorting in magento2.4.3p1 but it is not working in the frontend.
I am face issues is
**We can't find products matching the selection.**

```
Toolbar.php
<?php
namespace Bay20\Sorting\Plugin\Product\ProductList;
class Toolbar
{
    /**
    * Plugin
    *
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
    * @param \Closure $proceed
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
    */
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $currentOrder = $toolbar->getCurrentOrder();
        $currentDirection = $toolbar->getCurrentDirection();
        $result = $proceed($collection);

        if ($currentOrder) {
            switch ($currentOrder) {

            case 'newest':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('e.created_at DESC');
            break;

            case 'oldest':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('e.created_at ASC');

            break;

            case 'price_desc':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('price_index.min_price DESC');
            break;

            case 'price_asc':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('price_index.min_price ASC');
            break;

            case 'name_az':
                $this->_collection
                      ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc');
            break;

            case 'name_za':
                $this->_collection
                    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'desc');
            break;

            default:        
                $this->_collection
                    ->setOrder($currentOrder, $currentDirection);
            break;

            }
        }
 
        return $result;
    }
}

Also I have created config.php
<?php
namespace Bay20\Sorting\Plugin\Model;

class Config
{
    /**
     * Adding custom options and changing labels
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
     * @param [] $options
     * @return []
     */
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
        //Remove default sorting options
        /*unset($options['position']);
        unset($options['name']);*/
        unset($options['price']);

        //Change label of default sorting options if needed
        //$options['position'] = __('Relevance');

        //New sorting options
        $options['price_desc'] = __('Price High - Low');
        $options['price_asc'] = __('Price Low - High');
        $options['newest'] = __('Newest');
        $options['oldest'] = __('Oldest');
        $options['name_az'] = __('Product Name A - Z');
        $options['name_za'] = __('Product Name Z - A');

        return $options;
    }
}

etc\di.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="Bay20_Sorting::addCustomSortOptions" type="Bay20\Sorting\Plugin\Model\Config" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="Bay20_Sorting::implementCustomSortOptions" type="Bay20\Sorting\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: It seems your question is similar to the below mentioned question. Please check and try to solve your issue. "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-sort-by-option"

Comment: I have tried the solution but not worked in 2.4.3 p1. @SiranjeeviKS