# created_at sorting not working in Magenot 2.4 using elasticsearch

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, sort

I have created a custom sorting using created_at but result is empty.

when i checked logs it shows error

```
main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause": 
[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [created_at] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v65","node":"XzZz9kESSCq16bObBpx11w","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [created_at] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [created_at] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory.","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [created_at] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."}}},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [created_at] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory.\"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v65\",\"node\":\"XzZz9kESSCq16bObBpx11w\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [created_at] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory.\"}}],\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [created_at] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory.\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [created_at] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory.\"}}},\"status\":400} at /home/ubuntu/mag/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:632)"} []
```

But when i run this commands to solve the issue

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/created_at/_mapping?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: 
application/json' -d'
{
"properties": {
"created_at": {
  "type":     "text",
  "fielddata": true
}
}
}'
```

but this error shows

```
{
      "error" : {
        "root_cause" : [
          {
            "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
            "reason" : "no such index [created_at]",
            "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
            "resource.id" : "created_at",
            "index_uuid" : "_na_",
            "index" : "created_at"
          }
        ],
        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index [created_at]",
        "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id" : "created_at",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "created_at"
      },
      "status" : 404
    }
```

Is anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue and sorting is working perfectly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @RafaelFagundes Not Exactly but with these SQL queries help me to run this check this post https://magento-qa.com/magento-2-4-1-sort-by-newest-not-working

Comment: Yes, i use this same solution. It was the only that actually worked. thanks.

Comment: You have to add ‚crated_at’ to elasticsearch. You can try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/364360/97966 .

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch support filtering only by eav attribute marked as "filterable".

I "created_at" is not defined as eav attribute so, it's not available in the search

Comment: Thanks for your response KAndy. Can you please tell me how to make it aval. for searching and sorting